# ag output appears different in the terminal vs when piped to a file

Tags: terminal, io-redirection

When I run the `ag` command to search text files, I get output that looks like this on the command line (full results not shown):

```
❯ ag dependency
140317155505.md
27:The Bundler dependencies API ...

140423193022_python_packages.md
61:`distutils` is part of the Python standard ....
```

There are newlines in the output. However, when I pipe or redirect to a file, I get output like this:

```
140317155505.md:27:The Bundler dependencies API...
140423193022_python_packages.md:61:`distutils` is part of the Python standard...
```

Here there is an extra colon instead of a newline. How does this work? I would think that `ag` just writes to STDOUT and is unaware of the actual target of STDOUT-- am I wrong in thinking that it does not have access to this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program `ag` (I'm not familiar with it), could use the system call

```
stdout_is_tty = isatty(1);
```

> The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal.

This allows it to modify the output depending on where it is writing to.

I also think I found the relevant [source code section](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/17acedcb2964aceb4d0e0dc8cc6a6e7ede94a388/src/options.c#L268)

```
/* If we're not outputting to a terminal. change output to:
* turn off colors
* print filenames on every line
*/
if (!isatty(fileno(stdout))) {
  opts.color = 0;
  group = 0;
....
```

See also `man isatty`.

Comment: awesome, wish I give bonus points for the source code citation!

Answer (score 6):

I got here by Google and didn't quite find the answer I was looking for: you can invoke ag as

```
ag --color --group
```

to force it to use the default colors and group results by file, regardless of whether the output is a tty.

Here's [what it looks like in action](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10512059).